# redhat - using yum list available to query EL6, EL7, EL8 repos for specific package

Tags: list, redhat, rpm, yum

Kinda new to redhat el and have inherited this machine. I have a redhat EL7 machine.  I want to use yum list available  to see what package version are available on EL6, El7, EL8.  Since I have some packages that are from all those versions.

What repository do I have to add to see which version of packages are available in all those versions of redhat?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [package browser](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser) in the customer portal.

What problem are you trying to solve? There might be a better way than comparing package names and versions.